# Modifying the argument of a function without passing a pointer

Tags: c

I was just reading the GMP (a bignum library) [documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Integers.html#Initializing-Integers). It seems to be able to modify the arguments of a function. For example, initializing an integer works like this:

```
mpz_t integer;
mpz_init(integer);
// ... Do some stuff
mpz_clear(integer);
```

`mpz_init` allocates memory for an integer, `mpz_clear` frees it. If you had to pass a pointer, you could modify the function argument (`mpz_init(&integer)`), but it seems like this works without passing a pointer. How does this work?

Comment: `mpz_t` could be a pointer, or a struct that holds a pointer internally.

Comment: `mpz_init` possibly is a function-like macro instead of a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referring to this [source](https://gmplib.org/manual/Parameter-Conventions.html)

> For interest, the GMP types `mpz_t` etc are implemented as one-element arrays of certain structures. This is why declaring a variable creates an object with the fields GMP needs, **but then using it as a parameter passes a pointer to the object**.

`mpz_t` is defined in `gmp.h` file as

```
typedef struct
{
    //struct body
} __mpz_struct;

typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

So, basically `mpz_t` type is an array (of structure) type. Remember that arrays decay to pointer to its first element when passed to a function.